# Defining interface as variable type in JAVA

Tags: java, interface

How is it possible to define a variable type as an interface :

```
List<BigDecimal> filter = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();
```

Shouldn't we define a variable by class or primitive data types and not an interface as follows :

```
ArrayList<BigDecimal> filter = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();
```

How is it accepting interface variable definition?

Comment: FYI, it's called programming to an interface. You can find several references on the web.

Comment: Also "Java" is not an acronym o(>< )o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's *preferred* to code to interfaces (your first example, declare the variable using the interface, not the class). That way, if you need to change to a different implementation, it's trivial to do that — you just change the `new` to something else, and nothing else needs to change, because you code to the *interface*.

The reason it works is that `ArrayList<BigDecimal>` implements `List<BigDecimal>`, and so is assignment-compatible with it. That means that a variable declared as `List<BigDecimal>` is allowed to haev a reference of type `ArrayList<BigDecimal>` assigned to it. It's a design feature of the language. This is fundamental to how interfaces, and indeed OOP in general, works in Java.

Comment: Well yeah it seems duplicate but the answer was good to clear the point. Sorry for the bad formatting at first i will make sure its better for next time. Thank you :)